# PHP stops page unexpectedly after executing some lines, segfaults

Tags: javascript, php, apache, memcached, rackspace-cloud

**PHP Version** = 5.3,
**OS** = CentOS 6,
**Provider** = Rackspace,
**Type** = Cloud

---

## QUESTION

So I have a php page naming `page_two.php` of 195 lines. I call this page from `page_one.php` in the following way:

```
if(result=='success')
{
    var params =  'top=0, left=0';
    params += ', width='+screen.width+', height='+screen.height+',statusbar=no,toolbar=no, location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=no';
    params += ', scrollbars=yes, status=no, fullscreen=yes, titlebar=no';
    newwin=window.open("page_two.php","_blank",params);
    if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

The above codes opens the php page in a new popup like window.

Now this page works fine on my local system with no error, also works on my shared godaddy server. Recently I brought a Rackspace cloud server and uploaded the same file onto it. However I also installed things like **Memcached, memcache + libevent, and eAccelaretor**.

My whole website is working fine. The only problem I am facing is the page stops executing after a specific line on this cloud server.

So I have the following code block that opens the connection and establishes the session through `config.php` page:

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['my_code'])){header('Location:index.php');}
?>
```

Then I have whole lot of html code with CSS javascript and external files (css and js only).

I am doing an echo from session on `LINE 111`:-

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['my_code']; ?>
```

And the above ecoz the code with no problem.

Then I have another echo on line number `175`

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['getText1']; ?>
```

But after coming to this line of code page stops and no further code (html and php both) displays.

And that I can see from source code in Mozilla and Chrome that all lines till `LINE 174` is loaded which I can see in Mozilla, however on Google chrome i am unable to see anything in front end but in mozilla i can see the html part in front end till 174 line number.

So I have done an extensive search on internet but nothing I could be able to find yet. The main doubt which I have is, Is it a server related error or misconfiguration or maybe I have to do a php update or maybe there is some php stuff that I need to change. I am actually clueless, its programming or server.

What i can assure is that its not the **popup** problem as it also wont work when I directly navigate to that page.

Does anyone faced this kind of issue. I have been with PHP since 6 years now and this is the first time I am finding such problem, however I am new to cloud servers, so I may have done some mis-configuration there. Looking for your valuable comments.

---

## PROGRESS 1

### Is it something related to memory stuff??

**I saw this [article](http://academe.co.uk/2012/12/apache-segmentation-fault-11-related-to-memory/) from  Jason Judge but i am really clueless on what exactly needs to be done, this is a problem which exists for sure but there is no solution prescribed, atleast I am unable to find it. Can somebody look into this, because its really life threatening**

**Also I feel its positively something related to APACHE or something to be done with memory or caching, because just PHP i really don't feel anything is wrong as it works fine with localhost and my Godaddy shared server, problem persists with the Rackspace cloud hosting only. What you guyz think what could be the possible issue that causing this problem?**

**The thing is it just fails on `<?php ?>` script, so if I remove this line `<?php echo $_SESSION['getText1']; ?>` it fails on the next `<?php ?>` PHP code block**

---

## EDITS

**EDIT 1:**

No errors in php log file related to sessions

**EDIT 2**

When I check in Google chrome Console its hows me a red cross with the file like `http://myserver.com/page_two.php` with `page_two.php:1`

and when i click on the like it takes me to the chrome network tab and displays the following information for the file:

[image]

I have the following header information:

```
Request URL:http://mywebsite.comm/page_two.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH:AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.2
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=i4oqva0ruaahg6gcmnsslc64e3
Host:mywebsite.com
Referer:http://mywebsite.com/page_one.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 16 Dec 2013 12:43:34 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3
```

**EDIT 3 - After going through the php error logs I found this weird error message which really makes no sense to me of whats wrong happening**

`[Tue Dec 17 13:23:09 2013] [notice] child pid 19700 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`

#### WHEN I DO ECHO OF THESE SESSION ON PAGE TOP IT WORKS JUST FINE. ITS NOTHING TO DO WITH SESSION, AS WHEN I JUST SIMPLY ECHO "HI" STILL IT WONT ECHO IT AND PAGE STOPS EXECUTING THERE

Comment: Do you have errors turned on so that it will show you any errors that come up? Also can you check the error log and paste any errors you get? Your error log may be in: `/var/log/`.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log? If a fatal error is encountered PHP will stop execution after that point.

Comment: php generated no error in log.

Comment: Can you post lines 170-180 from page_two.php? It's possible that $_SESSION['getText1'] is empty so it's not actually printing a value, but dying after that code. Alternatively you could try this to ensure something is printed out: ```<?php echo "SESSION-getText1: ". $_SESSION['getText1']; ?>```

Comment: @ChrisRasco That's the problem, if I simply put `<?php echo "Hi" ?>` still it won't work, This is really odd, Do you think that can be a problem from Memcached, memcache + libevent, or eAccelaretor stuff. I am not sure as I am new to all these.

Comment: That seg fault is clearly your issue. Without seeing any of the code before the line that won't print, I can't even begin to tell you why it's seg faulting. It's unlikely an issue with that getText1 session variable, but you could wrap it in a test to validate that it's set before echoing it ```<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['getText1'])) echo "SESSION-getText1: ". $_SESSION['getText1']; ?>``` I still need to see the code above that line to truly help.

Comment: @ChrisRasco Actually its nothing to do with SESSIONS, as if even I just do a simple `echo` it stops executing the page from that line. I have edited my question a bit, kindly reconsider.

Comment: @DjangoAnonymous I know it's unrelated to the actual Sessions. I work for Rackspace. Can you email me at the address in my profile?

Comment: @ChrisRasco Just mailed you with server details

Comment: @ChrisRasco Thanks for your help I have figured out the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out. As I was kind of suspected with the Memcached, memcache + libevent, and eAccelaretor from start, I just uninstalled these three services and now the webpage works fine.

Now i need to figure out, out of these which one was created issues and will update my answer back.

Thanks for everyone help and support.

Answer (score 4):

When PHP exits with `segmentation fault` it means there's something wrong with your PHP installation and not your code. And usually it's an extension miss-match. You need to pin point which extension it is. Or you can use gdb to debug PHP, [here's how it is done](https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php).

If you find it hard to follow the debug steps, you can always roll back few steps to a state in which the error does not occur. Then adding steps forward one by one and see when the bug is introduced. All this is done much easier if you could come up with a much simpler code which reproduces the bug.